# Can I PWM an SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm using a [Pololu off-the-shelf SMPS](https://www.pololu.com/product/2857) to drive a small motor. Can I control the speed of the motor by tying the regulator's EN line into a PWM signal, or is there something about an SMPS or inductive load that'll make that not work?

Comment: SMPS supplies are a carefully select group of parts. The MOSFET  frequency and transformer are a 'tuned' circuit. The feedback for voltage regulation will tolerate 5% change at most. Interrupting the oscillator, assuming you can, is asking for trouble. Tampering with finely built circuits is a good way to blow the MOSFET or PWM IC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the part number of the switching controller in their documentation, but it is highly likely to have slow start circuitry to limit the start-up stress.  This will prevent you from using PWM on the EN line to control the power out.

Pololu and others make brushed DC motor controllers with PWM inputs, why not use something that was designed for the task?

Comment: hobby project, parts on hand. i'll look at the controllers, thanks.